# From where can I get python27.dll and wxmsw dll

Tags: python, wxpython

Our current project is made up of Python2.3 and wxPython-2.4.1.2. It is working fine. But now we are upgrading it to Python2.7 and wxPython2.8.12.1.
As I am new to Python and installation dlls, I need little guidence.
There are following files present in my NSIS installation folder for old Python:
python23.dll
wxmsw24h.dll

As this project was made by previous programmer, I don't know from where he got these dlls or how he made this dll.
I think, to make the installation program for my new python, I will need the following dlls:
python27.dll
wxmsw28h.dll

As per I understand, for wxmsw dll, I need to compile wxPython-src but not sure what can I do for this?

Please let me know, from where can I get these dlls? If I need to create it then please let me know, how can I create these dlls?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using to distribute? Try out `cx_Freeze` (it does all of this automatically). I've tried almost every single possible Python freezer and it is the only one that works with everything I throw at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python DLL:

```
c:\WINDOWS\system32\python27.dll
```

or:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\python27.dll
```

wxPython DLLs:

```
c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\wxbase28uh_net_vc.dll
c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\wxbase28uh_vc.dll
c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\wxbase28uh_xml_vc.dll
c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\wxmsw28uh_adv_vc.dll
c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\wxmsw28uh_aui_vc.dll
c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\wxmsw28uh_core_vc.dll
c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\wxmsw28uh_gizmos_vc.dll
c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\wxmsw28uh_gizmos_xrc_vc.dll
c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\wxmsw28uh_gl_vc.dll
c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\wxmsw28uh_html_vc.dll
c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\wxmsw28uh_media_vc.dll
c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\wxmsw28uh_qa_vc.dll
c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\wxmsw28uh_richtext_vc.dll
c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\wxmsw28uh_stc_vc.dll
c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\wxmsw28uh_xrc_vc.dll
```

But if you install Python and wxPython using installer, you should not need to copy it anywhere if you are not building binary. If you are building standalone binary, see Blender's comment.

Comment: This answer is really helpful.
First I need to remove the existing strange way of creating exe and then I will add cx_freeze.
Currently we got three things for this:
py2exe is installed in site-packages.
pyrun folder which has main.c and splash.c file.
And scandep.py file in the "install" folder.
First I need to understand, what is all these. Thanks.

Comment: BTW there are a lot of ways how to use cx_freeze, I was always happy with just a batch file call like this: `c:\Python27\Scripts\cxfreeze.bat main.py --target-dir=../Bin --base-name=Win32GUI --icon=../Data/icon.ico --target-name=MyApp.exe`

Comment: Thank you for sending this command. It makes my life easier. When I compile, it is giving me the following error:
Missing modules:
? System imported from serial.serialcli
? TERMIOS imported from serial.serialposix
? clr imported from serial.serialcli

Comment: It probably could not recognize some of your imported modules. You may want to use `--include-modules` option. The cx_freeze documentation is good http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/cx_Freeze.html and the mailing list active.

Comment: I found that this is the problem in Python. On the Python terminal if I write "import serial", then it is giving the same error e.g. Module not found at line "import clr" in file serialcli.py. But I don't know, why it is not found. I have just fresh installed. Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: `serial` is not standard Python module. You probably need [`PySerial`](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net) module.

Comment: I have already installed PySerial. And the error is in file serialcli.py file at the line where "import clr" statement written. But don't have any idea that the standard PySerial module uses "import clr" and from where it is expected to be. As per I understand, It should be either in Python or PySerial itself. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be standard module of IronPython.

Comment: `python27.dll` was under `SysWOW64`, not `system32`, on two of my machines. I've updated this answer to mention that it may be installed in that other directory.